Asset validation failed (90476) in .NET MAUI
When i upload my MAUI iOS app to the transporter app, i am getting this error. I am using custom splash.xaml. That use for both android and iOS. Also I have remove default splashscreen in MAUI project. also i have created LaunchScreen.storyboard inside iOS folder.
> Asset validation failed (90476)

Invalid bundle. Because your app supports Multitasking on iPad, you need to include the LaunchScreen launch storyboard file in your com.addovation.ios.mobileaction bundle. Use UILaunchScreen instead if the app’s MinimumOSVersion is 14 or higher and you prefer to configure the launch screen without storyboards. For details, see:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uilaunchstoryboardname
(ID: 5aeb38d6-340b-4186-b35f-c78b7df8144e)

This is my info.plist
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>    
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/appicon.appiconset</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Test App</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Mobile Action</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>test.ios.app</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>3.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>3.0.0</string>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>16.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>test.ios.app</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>msauth.test.ios.app</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>mailto</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
</dict>
</plist>


You can try this method first: RequiresFullScreen.

THank you i will try it @JessieZhang-MSFT

Waiting for your good news. :)

If you want to set RequiresFullScreen For iPhone, and support iPad Multitasking, please try the following code:
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName~ipad</key>
<string>LaunchScreenIPad.storyboard</string>
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
<true/>
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen~ipad</key>
<false/>


